# How can i impliment gmail like compose box which takes multiple users as recipient,

Tags: javascript, html, plugins, gmail

i am trying to use a free tempate from the given link https://github.com/almasaeed2010/AdminLTE
and use mailbox/compose.html page for mail services how can i take mutiple recipient as input in **To** input box as gmail take shown in picture below

[image]

Comment: `<input type=email multiple>`

Comment: @dandavis How to make them tag by putting **comma** "," after each email id ?

Comment: If i understood you well you can use the [select 2](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#tags) it can do the job

Comment: http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/gettingstarted

Comment: Is mails are brought from database or they are static?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `&` to add multiple **`To`**'s.
See example below.

https://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm&fs=1&to=someone@example.com&someoneelse@example.com&su=SUBJECT&body=BODY&bcc=someone.else@example.com

You can choose `To`, `cc`, `bcc`, `su` (for subject) and `body`, as shown.

```
https://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm&fs=1&to=someone@example.com&someoneelse@example.com&su=SUBJECT&body=BODY&bcc=someone.else@example.com
```